# How to migrate a .NET Framework application? [3.5 to 2.0]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, migration, .net-3.5

I am trying to make a migration of an application (*windows forms*).
Its framework is **3.5** but I want to convert it into framework **2.0**.

It occurred to me to create a new application (*with framework 2.0*) and then copy the code respectively, but there are too many "forms" and the idea is to save time.

Does anyone know of any method to migrate the application to a previous framework than the current one?

I hope you can help me.  Thanks.

Comment: your first question should be, why on earth would anyone still use .net 2.0

Comment: This seems pretty weird. Why do you want to convert it back? Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you explain the reason?

Comment: Labor issues, not everyone understands that it must go forward.

Comment: @BrandCodes pretty good indicator to go on and find another company. .net 2.0 is like 13 years old and the support has ended long ago.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I've already taken it into account, I'll start looking for another company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the Properties for the project, and on the Application tab set the target framework to whatever you want. This is from VS2017, but it should look similar in VS2010:

[image]

After that, you'll still have to go through and fix code that won't compile under the older framework.

Comment: is correct, now we just need to solve every error generated by the references and properties. Thanks @asherber.